# rallydev - query for custom grid - how to show tasks where work product is tagged

Tags: task, parent-child, rally

I am trying to create a query for a custom grid. I want to show all tasks where the work product (user story the tasks belong to) is tagged with a specific tag.

For example: 
US101 - Build a house  (tags = architecture, external)  
       Task1 - ***_*__*_*___** 
        Task2 - **__*_*__*_*__**  
US102 - Build a school (tags = architecture) 
        Task3 - ***_*__*_*__*_*_**

How do I create a query that will show task1, task2, and task3 based on the fact that their work products have the tag = architecture ?   (I know I can go through and manually tag every task under it and then do a query on task tags, but this is a huge pain, especially if tasks are added)

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom grid of tasks and use this as the query:

```
(WorkProduct.Tags.Name contains "architecture")
```